# can't read sha256 from nested array within mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sha256

I have below structure of the mongoose collection.

```
const sha256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');

    var Temp = new Schema();

    Temp.add({
        item1: String,
        item2: String,
        data: [
            {
                arrItem1: Number,
                arrItem2: String
            }
        ],
        recurData: [Temp],
        currentHash: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        previousHash: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    });
```

I am calculating the currentHash value as below:

```
return sha256(this.item1 + JSON.stringify(this.data) + this.previousHash).toString();
```

So, the issue is when I try to read the currentHash value as below and I am getting the output as "undefined".

```
var Temp = new Temp({//Initialised the data});
var latestDocument = Temp.recurData[Temp.RecurData.length - 1];
console.log(latestDocument.currentHash);
```

Could someone please advise if it's an existing issue or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the resolution that the ordering of the properties inside the schema is incorrect. It should be placed as the last property.

```
const sha256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');

    var Temp = new Schema();

    Temp.add({
        item1: String,
        item2: String,
        data: [
            {
                arrItem1: Number,
                arrItem2: String
            }
        ],        
        currentHash: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        previousHash: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        recurData: [Temp]
    });
```